# How to use CONCAT_WS/GROUP_CONCAT in LIKE Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I am trying to execute below query which says

```
SELECT t1.name from table t1, t2 WHERE t2.data LIKE(CONCAT_WS(',' DISTINCT(t1.name)))
```

OR

```
SELECT t1.name from table t1, t2 WHERE t2.data LIKE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(t1.name) SEPARATOR ','))
```

Both ways say

```
#1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT has a DISTINCT option.. `GROUP_GONCAT(DISTINCT ...)`  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: I am new to Mysql, will you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Can you please share the sample data and it's expected output. so all can get to know what you trying to achieve

Comment: Data is just names of people

Comment: _“Data is just names of people”_ - that is just a vague verbal description of your data, not actual _sample data_. Please provide example data for input and desired output. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184691/how-to-ask-sql-questions-with-table-definitions-and-example-code

Comment: Also http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#symptoms

Answer (score 0):

Well not totally sure what trying to do, but suspect will need a subquery to join on an aggregate function.

```
 SELECT names
  FROM t2
  INNER JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name SEPARATOR ',') as names
    FROM t1 
    GROUP BY user_id) t1 USING t2.data = names
```

That query still doesnt really make sence, but might show **roughly** how to construct it.

As comments say, really need more context to under WHAT you trying to do.